# invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' for map(int, str(num))

Tags: python

I am running a recursive function that takes in a positive integer and a list (that is updated as it runs through the function):

```
def happy_number(num, tracking_list = []):
    if (num == 1):
        print 1
    else:
        digit_list = map(int, str(num)) 
        digit_sum = 0
        for n in digit_list:
            digit_sum = (n ** 2) + digit_sum
        if digit_sum in tracking_list:
            print 0
        else:
            tracking_list.append(digit_sum)
            happy_number(digit_sum, tracking_list)
```

When running this, it complains about:

```
digit_list = map(int, str(num))
```

it gives the error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

What is happening here?

Comment: What input are you giving it?

Comment: @AmiTavory Apparently he is feeding in an empty string as num

Comment: The code appears fine, you are giving num="" for your input.

Comment: @RPGillespie If you feed an empty string it will not raise this error, it will return `[]`. I think he is passing `' '` maybe (that is a single space in a string)?

Comment: @RPGillespie Thanks! However, it just prints 0 for me when given an empty string.

Comment: @elethan You got it.

Comment: Can we see the code where you call this function?  It looks like your `num` isn't actually a number.

Comment: sorry, I should have been more clear.  There is a list of inputs I'm feeding this.  1 positive integer each line.

Comment: @user1072337 AH! you are passing it a newline probably! Is your list being parsed from a file?

Comment: My guess is that you are `print 1` and `print 0` when you should `return` value.

Comment: @elethan yes.  This is where it's called.  with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as test_cases:
    for test in test_cases:
        happy_number(test, [])

Comment: `test` is a string - it's read from text file, and conversions are never done in Python implicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are parsing your numbers from a file, and when a space `' '` or a newline `'\n'` shows up (or anything that is not a string digit for that matter), your script will fail. You can try:

```
def happy_number(num, tracking_list = []):
    if (num == 1):
        print 1
    else:
        digit_list = map(int, str(num if num.isdigit() else ''))
        digit_sum = 0
        for n in digit_list:
            digit_sum = (n ** 2) + digit_sum
        if digit_sum in tracking_list:
            print 0
        else:
            tracking_list.append(digit_sum)
            happy_number(digit_sum, tracking_list)
```

The line:

```
digit_list = map(int, str(num if num.isdigit() else ''))
```

Will do the same thing as what you had before, except will be an empty list `[]` if you pass `num` is not a string digit. Replace the `''` at the end with another default to if you wish.